# If-else indentation

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, indentation

I am playing with python3.5 right now. I was working on a simple code, to find the prime numbers less than a given integer. I solved the code more by mistake and I don't know why. This is the code:

```
n=int(input('Enter a numeric value: '))

for num in range(2, n+1):
    if num>1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num%i)==0:
                break
        else:   
            print(num)
```

What I don't seem to understand is why if i write the code like above it gives a correct answer, and if i write the else statement with one more indentation, the output is different. Ex:

Enter a numeric value: 10

3

5

5

5

7

7

7

7

7

9

for:

```
...if num>1:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num%i)==0:
            break
        else:   
            print(num)
```

I feel the need to mention that I just started to learn python so please take me slow:D

Comment: You don't need to write `if num>1:` since `num` will iterate in the range 2..(n+1) which means that `num` will _always` be greater than 1.

Comment: I mostly let it there so I can fastly modify the code if I want a prime no. in a certain range. Ex. I enter `low=input()` for the bottom value of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` is associated with the `for`. Indenting it farther associates it with the `if`.

- An `else` after an `if` runs if the `if` didn’t
- An `else` after a `for` runs if the `for` didn’t `break`

You want the latter behaviour, since you `break` if you found a factor for the number.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes I really get mind-blocked by such simple things...